# Angular SyntaxError JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: angular, angular-http

im making a http get request to and specific url and the response is a string (base64 images) using this method:

```
  public getSingleImage(imgId): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const url = `${CONST.DOCUMENT_SINGLE_IMAGE}/${imgId}` + '/base64';
      this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then((res: any) => {
          // value = res;
          resolve(res);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

for some reason i getting the error `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Here is the response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
api-supported-versions: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2018 14:01:07 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
```

Comment: could your add the response header to your question, it seems that angular think the response is some JSON and try to parse it. You certainly have a application/json content-type on the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [new angular's HTTP module](https://angular.io/guide/http) is now in default expecting for JSON response from server. If you want to change it you need to add a proper HTTP header.
try to add this header:

```
{'responseType':'image/*'}
```

So your get request should look like :

```
 this.http.get(url,{
 'responseType':'image/*'
})
```